# How to observe if a field is there in RestKit. Setter is not invoked when the value is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit

I have a notification mechanism in my app. Basicly I have a field which is send with every response and I am posting a notification when value of this field changes. Is there a way I can know when the field was not sent at all?

Right now the field needs to be there so my setter is invoked while `RestKit` is doing the mapping and I can post a notification. However it would be better not to send this field when there is no need and I got a callback that the field disappeared.

Here is a simplified code illustrating the problem:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *myPreciousNumber;

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mappingForClass;

@end



@implementation MyClass


+ (RKObjectMapping *)mappingForClass
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@
     {
         @"myPreciousNumber" : @"myPreciousNumber"
     }];

     return mapping;
}


- (void)setMyPreciousNumber:(NSNumber *)myPreciousNumber
{
    _myPreciousNumber = myPreciousNumber;

    // Post a value changed notification here.
}
```

Obviously, the setter is not invoked when there is no field send in the response. It is also not invoked when the value of the field is null.

I'd like to know if there is a way to either invoke the setter when the value sent is null or there is a different way to know when the field is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at setting `setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` on your mapping, but that would likely lead to side effects that you don't want.

KVO would be a better solution than your own notification anyway (`addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`).

You really need to be more clear about the reason for your notification solution as it 99% isn't the correct approach. Posting change notifications from a single variable when you seem to want broader notifications of object level changes indicates that your change notifications would be better handled in the RestKit `success` callback block than in the objects themselves.

Comment: Setting the `setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` to `YES` had no effect. However, thanks to pointing me in a correct direction. I moved the notifications logic to my generic success handler. It's much more clean right now.